# Play Games - Quick game causes UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, unsatisfiedlinkerror, google-play-games

I'm already successfully using Play Games for achievements and leaderboard, and now I'm trying to implement the multi-player system (I've enabled it in the Developer Console).

As described [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/multiplayer#quick_game_option), this code should launch the quick game activity :

```
    if (getGamesClient().isConnected()) {
        Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 1, 0);

        RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
        roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(am);
        RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();

        getGamesClient().createRoom(roomConfig);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```

It is in fact working on my Nexus 7, but not with my Galaxy S4. 
The onRoomCreated event is not called and I get a ARM
The only hint I have is these lines in the logcat :

```
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at ajd.<init>(SourceFile:361)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at ajd.a(SourceFile:476)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at ara.<init>(SourceFile:120)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.RealTimeMatchAndroidService.onBind(SourceFile:73)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:2647)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:152)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1375)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load games_rtmp_jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar:/system/app/GmsCore.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1]: findLibrary returned null
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    at com.google.android.gms.games.jingle.Libjingle.<clinit>(SourceFile:38)
07-06 14:15:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22967):    ... 15 more
```

UPDATE : 
I no longer have the problem. I backup my phone, install another ROM (it was working, so I developped it) and then reinstallt he backup and it started working. In the mean time have revoke the connection between my Google+ account and my app (google+ app -> settings -> Google+ sign in).
So I don't know which one really solved my problem.

Comment: Check the version of Google Play on the N7 & S4. does the S4 have the latest version of Google Play on it? (which pulls down the latest google stuff that Google Play Services uses I assume).

Comment: Yes, I have le same version 3.1.36(669520-30).